# How to write a style for HyperlinkButton Shadow effect in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-interface, styles

I have a styled HyperlinkButton as per custom need as follow:

```
<HyperlinkButton Tag="Transactions/HomeWorkPage"
                 Background="#E9E9EB" Foreground="Black">
       <HyperlinkButton.Effect>
           <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" Opacity="0.35" ShadowDepth="3"/>
       </HyperlinkButton.Effect>
       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <Image Source="/SchoolMgmt;component/Assets/Images/R_Homework.png"
               Margin="10,0,1,0"/>
           <telerik:Label Content="Home Work" CharacterSpacing="25"
               telerik:StyleManager.Theme="{Binding SelectedTheme,Mode=TwoWay}"
               FontSize="12" FontFamily="Arial Rounded MT" Margin="3"/>
        </StackPanel>                                            
 </HyperlinkButton>
```

Now with satisfy with the result I started to write a style resource for this so that I can use wherever I want.

This is I am able to write:

```
<Style x:Name="QuickLinkStyle" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#E9E9EB"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
</Style>
```

I am not able to convert following into style

```
<HyperlinkButton.Effect>
    <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" Opacity="0.35" ShadowDepth="3"/>
</HyperlinkButton.Effect>
```

I am not a designer and not using expression blend for writing a style. I tried to googled it. But all I able to find out is DataTemplate , VisualStates etc. Its very confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is not working?

```
<Style x:Name="QuickLinkStyle" TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
    ...
    <Setter Property="Effect">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DropShadowEffect .../>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```